# Angular10 - waiting for first line to finish

Tags: angular, promise

I have the following:

search component:

```
search(zipcode){
  this.apiService.getRestaurants(zipcode);
  console.log(this.restaurants);
}
```

service:

```
  getRestaurants(zip:string){
    this.http.get('../assets/data/' + zip + '.json').toPromise().then(
    results=>{
        console.log(results);
        this.mydata = results;
        return this.mydata;
    }
  );
}
```

`getRestaurants` fetches a JSON file associated with the zip and sets it to `this.mydata` (although I could probably just return `results`, but hey). It prints out the JSON in `getRestaurants` but prints out `undefined` in the search component. I know I'm missing something obvious regarding resolving it before I send it back, but my GoogleFu is failing me today. How do I get the data back in the parent component to work with?

Comment: don't do what @abney317 said, you're gonna slow down you application

Answer (score 2):

You should change to this:

search component:

```
search(zipcode){
  this.apiService.getRestaurants(zipcode).then(restaurants => {
    this.restaurants = restaurants;
    console.log(this.restaurants);
  }
}
```

service:

```
getRestaurants(zip:string){
    return this.http.get('../assets/data/' + zip + '.json').toPromise().then(
    results=>{
        console.log(results);
        this.mydata = results;
        return this.mydata;
    }
  );
}
```

Although I am not sure why you are converting the observable the HttpClient returns to a promise, you should probably leave it as an observable.

Comment: `Although I am not sure why you are converting the observable the HttpClient returns to a promise, you should probably leave it as an observable.` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that typescript is doing you're console.log before you get your answer.

Use subscribe instead? Angular work really well with observable!! (See [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) librairie for more info)

Also I strongly suggest using typing in all your application AND change your variables so they have meaningful name.

Your service should look like this in theory:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestaurantService {
  
  private restaurantList: Restaurant[] = [];
  private restaurantListSubject: BehaviorSubject<Restaurant[]>
                      = new BehaviorSubject<Restaurant[]>([]);
  public restaurantList$(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.restaurantListSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public getRestaurants(zip:string): Observable<Restaurant[]>{
    this.http.get<Restaurant[]>('../assets/data/' + zip + '.json').pipe(
      tap(
        restaurants => {
          console.log(restaurants);
          this.restaurantList = restaurants;
          this.restaurantListSubject.next(this.restaurant);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Search component (you can subscribe there and console.log):

```js
export class SearchComponent {
  public search(zipcode): void {
    this.apiService.getRestaurants(zipcode).subscribe(restaurants => {
      console.log(restaurants); // will be defined
    });
    console.log(this.restaurants); // will be undefined
  }
}
```